# Render view inside an helper in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following view which I want to render it (called `Test.ascx`).

```
<div class='test'>
  <%=ViewBag.MyTranslation%>
</div>
<div class='link'>
  <a href="<%=Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id = Model })%>">Link</a>
</div>
```

An helper created by me:

```
public static string GetSomething(List<int> items)
{
   if(items == null || items.Count == 0)
   {
      return string.Empty;
   }

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   // many `if` here

   foreach(var num in items) 
   {
       // here I want to render the partial view and store it into string
   }
}
```

And in another view, I tried

```
<div class="main">
   // some html text

  // follow rule #11 
  // from http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/10/27/12-asp.net-mvc-best-practices.aspx

   <%=Html.GetSomething(Model.NumberList)
</div>
```

I tried to use a method from here http://akinyusufer.blogspot.in/2011/05/razor-render-mvc3-view-render-to-string.html

but it crash at `ViewBag`, gives null, also for `Url.Action` (`Url` is null).

There is another better solution to render view to string inside a string ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using helper.RenderPartial to render Test view:

```
public static void GetSomething(this HtmlHelper helper, List<int> items)
{
    foreach (var num  in items)
    {
        helper.RenderPartial("Test", num);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<% Html.GetSomething(Model.NumberList); %>
```

or change GetSomething to return MvcHtmlString and combine results from helper.Partial("Test", num) calls.